# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable - phpWord

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

I am trying to output html to word using phpWord. However, something is weird.  It works fine for the following code:

```
$content = '';
    $content .= '<table><tr><th>Header</th><td>Content</td></tr></table>';
    $content .= '<ul><li>Bullet</li><ul><li>Bullet</li></ul></ul>';
    $content .= '<ol><li>Bullet</li></ol>';
    Html::addHtml($newSection, $content);
```

But does not work for this:

```
 $content = '';
    $content .= '<table><tr><th>Header</th><td>Content</td></tr></table>';
    $content .= '<p>Bullet</p>';
    $content .= '<p>Cat</p>';
    Html::addHtml($newSection, $content);
```

and produces the error mentioned on the title.

**UPDATE**

This error is generated from this file: \vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Shared\Html.php

In this method:

```
 private static function parseChildNodes($node, $element, $styles, $data)
{
    if ('li' != $node->nodeName) {
        $cNodes = $node->childNodes;
        if (count($cNodes) > 0) {
            foreach ($cNodes as $cNode) {
                if ($element instanceof AbstractContainer) {
                    self::parseNode($cNode, $element, $styles, $data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it only happens when using the `<p>` html tag and it's fine with all other tags.

I also came across this link: [addHtml() does not support tags inside list tags. #521](http://Based%20on%20this:%20https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/521%20It%20seems%20like%20it's%20a%20bug,%20or%20it's%20just%20developed%20that%20way.)

Comment: @Daniel I am using laravel, and the reason I tagged "laravel" is because I am not sure where the error is generated from. I just find it strange that it doesn't work for <p> html tag but works on the one example.  I am also not working files.

Comment: Update your question with the entire error message, and include code snippets of the line and file specified by that error message. If you're getting an exception you may need to look closer at the stack trace to find out where the error actually is.

Comment: @Daniel - That's exactly what I did

Comment: What does `var_dump($newSection, $content);` tell you if you put that statement before `Html::addHtml($newSection, $content);` when it's not working? Just a note on the error message you posted with the question; Error messages in PHP always refer to a line and file where the error occurs - and the posted error message does not include that information.

Comment: Error messages tell usually source file and line. This info will help to encapsulate the error.

Comment: @Wiimm I believe this error is generated by phpWord library, because if it was just php/laravel this would not happen. Basically the two code snippets in the question are from the same file, and I just replaced the first one with the second one

Comment: @Daniel, Based on this: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/521 It seems like a bug, or it's just designed to throw this error when certain tags are used

Comment: @kya There you go! Good job on parsing the error message and looking at the right places. Without a detailed error there's no possibility for us to help you, as it can be due to anything that happens before, after or during the snippet you originally showed. To top it off, you're not using an up to date version of PHPWord which makes it even harder for us, since I actually did look up all places where the lib uses `count`, and found no related snippets. It's been refactored, so you should update; https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Shared/Html.php#L482